# Start/Stop adb daemon programmatically in android

Tags: adb

I want to make an app.which can start and stop adb daemon which i want to run on Google Nexus 7(Android 5.0.1).

I downloaded the nexus 7 source code and created an app. in packages/app folder and built it in system/priv-app.

I am using following code for starting and stoping adb daemon :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stop adbd");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start adbd");
```

But its not working.

It works fine on an emulator(Android 4.4), but not on the device.

Can any one please suggest if anything more needs to be done for the above code to work on device.

I am having the 
whole system code.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Quick guess: each `exec` starts a new process, so setting the properties in the first `exec` has no effect on the later ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert... On the emulator when i run the above code, i am able to start and stop the adb daemon from my application(also am able to set the tcp port to 5555 using the exec command--first line) . But the same code doesn't work on device. Am not even able to set the tcp port value on device(am verifying using adb shell getprop). Do i need to add more permissions?

Comment: for your commands you would need at least `system(uid=1000)` access level. check if your app gets properly recognized as *system app* on your device

Comment: Hi Alex. The app is built in system/priv-app folder. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I checked the logs and am getting following errors :- 
avc: denied { write } for pid=6628 comm="sh" na
me="tty" dev=tmpfs ino=2107 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=s
ystem_ubject_r:devtty_t tclass=chr_file.

This logs are related to selinux. Any idea how can i skip selinux policies?

Comment: @AmarSarode: Did you get any solution for this ?